# Does using furnace increase smithing skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've smelted quite a lot of ore (iron, silver, gold, etc.) into respective bars but it doesn't seem to get my smithing skill increase.
Is this a bug or does only making/improving objects increase this skill?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## No

Using a [Smelter](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smelting) does not increase your skill, similar to a [Tanning Rack](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Tanning).

Only actually making something using the [Forge](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Forge) or improving things using the [Grindstone](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Grindstone) or [Workbench](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Workbench) will give you [Smithing](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Smithing) experience.

Answer (score 3):

**NO, but, it could if you wanted it to...**

As [alexanderpas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/29/alexanderpas) said, no in the default game, however, if you're playing on a system that supports mods, and if you're interested in such things, the mod *Ars Metallica* by [Arthmoor](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/users/684492):

- Provide skill advancement for the use of the smelter to melt down ore. After all, that's as important as knowing how to shape it once refined.
- Provide skill advancement for the use of the tanning rack to make leather. That's far more important in my mind than the skill advances from using the leather to make stuff.
- Provide for a small amount of skill advancement from mining the ore itself out of ore veins.

This mod is available on Nexus by [Arthmoor](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/users/684492) for both [oldrim](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/users/684492) and [special edition](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/321) and on BethesdaNet also by [Arthmoor](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim?author_username=Arthmoor) for [PC](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2937280), [XBox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2937287), AND for [PS4](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/3919839).

Two things of note:  Arthmoor does a great job with mods and he's very prolific so definitely check out his stuff.  *Personally* I don't care for this mod, but that's really just me (as noted by the high rating of this mod everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

No, but if you look for a way to level Smithing get a lot of leather (pretty cheap).
and make leather glove!

It should give EXP in Smithing just like dragon armor do!